# More available memory after mobile device awakes from suspend mode?

Tags: memory-management, windows-ce

In a Windows CE application I measure the available memory as it was discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7135268/1326595. I very often see the effect, that after the mobile device awakes from suspend mode, there is more memory available to the application than before going to suspend mode. How to explain this? Is it possible to reproduce the effect without suspending the device?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say without knowing where the memory is being freed from. I'd suggest running [Device Health](http://intermec.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14340/~/devhealth%3A-memory-usage-tool-for-windows-ce-5) before and after the suspend and comparing the results.

Answer (score 1):

Windows CE flushes some caches and internal kernel page tables when suspending and this may actually free some memory in the system.
You can force flushing filesystem caches etc. and this may recover some RAM, but it's not granted at all.